# Website's Horizontal Scrollbar Not Working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, web, scrollbar

I've built a photography site that displays photos side by side, user scrolls though photos using a horizontal scrollbar. (link removed no longer works)

I have used the jscrollpane plugin to customize the look of the scrollbar, but I have disabled it for the time being as I look for a fix. The container is called .scroll-pane.

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work on an iPhone?

Thank you and happy new year

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that won't work on iOS. You can use two fingers to scroll such an element, but most people are not aware of that.

You should consider a responsive design that adjusts how your site functions in mobile browsers.

Comment: so horizontal scrollbars don't work at all on iphone or ipads?? 

I'm considering making a new structure only for mobiles, but that would require huge time investment on my part. I was hoping there would be an easier way :)

Comment: Your best bet may be left/right buttons on either side of the scrollable region that position the region via JavaScript. Google "jQuery carousel" for examples.